# How to handle character encoding with XML, JDom, JNI and C++

Tags: java, c++, character-encoding, java-native-interface, jdom

I am developing an application that reads in an XML document and passes the contents with JNI to a C++-DLL which validates it.

For this task I am using [JDom](http://www.jdom.org/) and [JUniversalChardet](http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/) to parse the XML file in the correct encoding. My C++ accepts a `const char*` for the contents of the XML file and needs it in the encoding "ISO-8895-15", otherwise it will throw an exception because of malformed characters.

My first approach was to use the shipped OutputFormatter of JDom and tell it to use `Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15")` while formatting the JDom document to a String. After that the header part of the XML in this String says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
```

The Problem is that it is still stored in a Java String and therefore UTF-16 if I got that right.

My native method looks something like this:

```
public native String jniApiCall(String xmlFileContents);
```

So I pass the above mentioned String from the OutputFormatter of JDom into this JNI-Method. Still everything UTF-16, right?

In the JNI-C++-Method I access the `xmlFileContents String` with

```
const string xmlDataString = env->GetStringUTFChars(xmlFileContents, NULL);
```

So, now I got my above mentioned String in UTF-16 or UTF-8? And my next question would be: how can I change the character encoding of the `std::string xmlDataString` to ISO-8859-15? Or is the way I am doing this not exactly elegant? Or is there a way to do the character encoding completely in Java?

Thanks for your help!
Marco

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert any `String` to byte array with needed character encoding using `byte[] getBytes(Charset charset)` method (or even `byte[] getBytes(String charsetName)`).

Comment: Okay... And how to I convert byte[] into std:string without the .NET API?

Comment: Just convert `byte[]` to `char*`. As you said above the needed type is `char *` in ISO-8859-15 encoding. So, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can maybe use `myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-15")`; to get the **byte array** of the String using the character encoding used as parameter (in this case `ISO-8859-15`).

And then use that byte array in `C` to get the `std::string` with something like:

```
std::string myNewstring ( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(myByteArray) )
```